Is it possible to reuse workflow_dispatch on GitHub actions across different repositories?
I want to add manually triggered workflow_dispatch to GitHub actions as follows:
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      rollbackSteps:
        description: "Input rollback steps"
        required: false
        type: number
        default: 1

the problem is there are around 8-10 different repositories which has their own workflows and I want to add this manual trigger to their GitHub actions
I want to avoid duplication by copy pasting same code to each GitHub actions. Is there a way to reuse the workflow. I have the image to create it as central file and then call this file something like that.
If it is not possible to reuse it is there a way to automate this like I define it once and it gets copies to all other repo files?

No, you can't deduplicate on.

Is there a way to automate this across all repositories?

Well at a certain level it's just writing text to a YAML file, which could be automated. Maybe you want some kind of template repo the others get created from.

I am already using that setup there is data so not able to use template repo.
However is there a way to add altogether a new file in the existing repository using template repo?

There is no feature to define a reusable trigger across multiple workflows, let alone across repositories.
GitHub Actions does have a "Required Workflow" feature, but that only supports the pull request and push triggers.
Technically taking this trigger and replicating it across different workflow files is possible. You'd need a repo that hosts the definition, put a github workflow in there that pushes the updated trigger definition into the other repos that use this trigger. You'd need either a Personal Access Token or a GitHub App token to be able to push to these other repositories.
Here is a sample repo that updates the contents of a few "child" repos. In our case we do a force-push, in your case that's probably not exactly what you want though.

https://github.com/XpiritBV/CodeToCloud-Workshop/blob/main/.github/workflows/update-child-repos.yml

